# Display selected parts from selected pages on the frontpage?

Tags: php, custom-field, pages, frontpage

I'm build a site for my company and want to display four (of my choise) of our special deals on our frontpage.
A special deal is a page.

I want to grab:

- Featured Image
- Page Title
- Price (taking from a custom field or something)
- Read More (link to the page)
- +I want to be able to determine whether the page will be displayed on the frontpage or not.

The sitemap look like this

- Home Our
- Special Deals

  - Special Deal #1
  - Special Deal #2
  - Special Deal #3
  - Special Deal #4
  - Special Deal #5
  - Special Deal #6
  - Special Deal #7
- Info
- Contact

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What help you are looking for precisely? Please show what code you have working already.

Comment: @Rarst No code. If you got a link to a tutorial or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a special category to specify what pages you want on your home page.

For the sake of this example, we'll call it "Featured".

So on each page that you want to show, just add the "Featured" category to it. Then, if you want to remove it from the home page you just un-check that category.

Just query for that category of pages like so on the home page template: (this is untested)

```
<?php $homefeatured = array(
'post_type'=>'page',
'post_status'=>'publish',
'cat'=> 'THE ID OF YOUR FEATURED CATEGORY',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $homefeatured );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        the_post_thumbnail();
        echo '<br />';
        the_title();
        echo '<br />';
        echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'CUSTOM_PRICE_FIELD');
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'">Read more ></a>';

    }
} else {
    // no featured deals found
}
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Paste this into functions file to add category support for pages:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'reg_tax');
function reg_tax() {
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');
  add_post_type_support('page', 'category');
}
```

Comment: This is really great stuff @Eckstein Thank you! but how do I add a category to a page, I know how to do it with posts but not with pages! Is "Special Category" a plugin or something?

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that categories are not native to pages. You could add category support for pages. See the above edit.

Comment: And no, special category is not a plugin. I just meant a category used exclusively for the featured home page purpose.

Comment: Got this Error message:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /www/public_html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mysite/homepage.php on line 27

Line 27: $query = new WP_Query( $homefeatured );

Comment: Looks like I forgot a semi-colon after the query args array. I corrected it above. Try it now.

Comment: Wooowww It works perfectly!!! Thank you so much @Eckstein !!! You are a hero! :)

Comment: No prob, glad to help!